# How to use an Self hosted agent in Azure Cloud

Tags: azure

I am using Microsoft agent to build my azure react pipeline, however due to firewall issue I can't use it in azure develops. As a consequence of it I need  to use self hosted agent. But not sure how to use self-hosted agents continuously running on cloud

Comment: Recently I was using self hosted agent in my local machine. You can follow below steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1tWj3ytVSQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been trying couples of ways to create self hosted agent for UI packages, however I ended up creating azure artifacts which can be used in our azure pipeline.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/?view=azure-devops

I hope this would be useful for you

Answer (score 1):

We have a GitHub repo that contains code to deploy self-hosted agents that run on Azure Container Instances, images stored in Azure Container Registry, and all deployed via Terraform. You can find the guide here (link contains YouTube video as well): https://cloudelements.ca/azure-devops-self-hosted-agents-with-aci-acr-and-terraform/